# Progressive web apps

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I'm facing a huge technical problem. I can't see "add to home screen". However, I did follow the installation guidelines.I want to know if I have created a small unintended malfunction and why it doesn't show up.

Link to the site : https://www.bclover.net

I apologize in advance, the site is in French. I hope that won't be too much of a hindrance to your assistance.

Thank you

EDIT :

Manifest.json

```
{
  "lang": "fr",
  "dir": "ltr",
  "name": "Black Clover FR",
  "short_name": "Bclover",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#000000",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/?utm_source=pwa",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "styles/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "styles/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "styles/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "styles/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "styles/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "styles/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "styles/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "styles/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "splash_pages": null
}
```

[Lighthouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wjRY.png)

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? If there are issues, it usually gives good hints. See start_url

Comment: Can you provide your manifest.json file contents here? Even if I can get it in your website by your link - it's recommended to keep it in stackoverflow for future

Comment: this done! @Mathias

Comment: this done! @java-man-script

Comment: You had to insert your first manifest.json in your answer too ))

Comment: @java-man-script => I'm still not very familiar with this help platform. Thanks for the advice. I edited my first post. Here as a comment, I can't put it here it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked out your website and saw error in the console that says sw.js file is responding with 404 error by the server:
[image]

So you have to checkout if the file exists on your server.

I recommend you to follow [this tutorial (web.dev)](https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/) by Google - well written.

In your case you have to register `service worker` which is shown how to do that in [this article (web.dev)](https://web.dev/codelab-make-installable/)

And I recommend you to use [Workbox library](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox) (this from Google too) to ease the pain while making PWA web app

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried the tutorial and I've followed this tutorial at the base: https://web.dev/add-manifest/

I did have PWA, but since I emptied the cache and cookies, I don't have them anymore on android or on my different browsers. I don't really understand the problem.

Comment: Updated the answer - check the answer again

Comment: Indeed, it is a valid link now.
But the pop-up that informs the installation of the PWA is still not displayed.

Comment: I see you fixed it - cause now I'm seeing the install button in address bar